# Registry entry for User Authentication?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

Does anyone know the registry location for the internet user authentication->logon section within windows?

Start->Control Panel->Internet Options

Then second tab over to "Security" there is a button "Custom Level" if you click that button and scroll all the way down you see this:

[image]

How can I find the registry setting for this area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones

There are sub-keys under that for each zone, they will hold all of the security settings as a dword, there is a list on the Microsoft website somewhere of what dword is what (I will post it when I find it)

Hope that helps.

**Edit:** Here is the link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569

Answer (score 5):

Reference the following article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users

Here there is mention that most of these options can be found within this key:

**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones**

You will see various zones (such as Zones 0-5) the number of these zones represent the following:

The Zones key contains keys that represent each security zone that is defined for the computer. By default, the following five zones are defined (numbered zero through four):

```
   Value    Setting
   ------------------------------
   0        My Computer
   1        Local Intranet Zone
   2        Trusted sites Zone
   3        Internet Zone
   4        Restricted Sites Zone
```

Note By default, My Computer does not appear in the Zone box on the Security tab.

**Local Intranet / Internet**

For local intranet/internet within **zones 1 and zones 3** there is a key named **1A00** here are the values:

- For **automatic login using current user name and password** the value should be set as 0
- For **prompt for user name and password** the value should be in hex 10000
- For **automatic logon only for intranet zone** the value should be 20000 in hex.
- For **anonymous logon** the value should be 30000 in hex.

Because we want to take advantage of windows authentication we want the value of the key named 1A00 to be simply 0 (first option listed above).

Here is the final result of the registry file (.reg) file to distribute to users:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]
"1A00"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1]
"1A00"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2]
"1A00"=dword:00000000
```